# Object Lifecycle Management - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to delete files older than 7 days from a specific GCS folder.
File names are randomly generated.

The structure is as below:

```
folder1
├── aswdfertg
├── fileewryhgrwt2
├── dfghdf
...
├── srty5rhr
└── srthrt
```

I was trying to use [matchesPrefix](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#matchesprefix-suffix) `"matchesPrefix":["folder1/*"]` but it doesn't work.
I'm not sure if `*` works as wildcards or not in this case.

Comment: Don't put the *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage Transfer Service supports the use of prefixes to select which files to include or exclude from the data source. You can use include prefixes, exclude prefixes, or both together.

As you have mentioned `"matchesPrefix":["folder1/*"]` doesn't work.
I'm not sure if `*` works as wildcards or not in this case.

Because Wildcards are not supported in gcp

Now you want to delete all the files in folder1 so the prefix will be `folder1/`, which means that all the files in that folder will be deleted.

Follow [filter by prefix](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/filtering-objects-from-transfers) for more options and information.